# Can we Zoom In/Out the Xib file View in XCode 4.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I want to Zoom Out my View in Xib file for using Storyboard in Xcode 4.0 so that it will clearly shows my all views on the one screen only and i don't have to use the scrolling (bored with this) everytime....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show all of your views you need to zoom out using the zoom controls at the bottom right of the screen as shown in this picture. [image: zoom in storyboard]

Comment: in my xcode this control is not shown... do we need to enable that????  But i am able to zoom to particular level with double clicking at empty space....

Comment: After going through Xcode and the documentation I believe it is probably a bug, that is making it not appear. If you click the Editor tab and go down to Canvas you can Zoom in and out by increments of 25% or Zoom in or Out completely it preforms the same function as the zoom guy element

Comment: Looks like this only applies to storyboards. Editor > Canvas > Zoom option is not available on a XIB, neither is the handy zoom controls shown in the lower right of the above screenshot.